Работа с фокусом внутри окна с виртуализацией
Появилась нужда сделать виртуализацию для окна в котором создаются textbox'ы так как при создании около тысячи элементов начинает подлагивать. Виртуализация действительно помогла, но появились проблемы с фокусом элементов. Логика следующая: по нажатию на Enter фокус переключается на следующий textbox, а если это последний элемент в коллекции то создается новый и фокус падает на него. Но после добавления виртуализации фокус работает адекватно только на видимой области, и если выходит за рамки видимого окна то фокус уже не переключается на следующий элемент, но элементы при этом создаются (видно как уменьшается полоса прокрутки) если прокрутить мышью то видно новые элементы. Также при смене фокуса между уже созданными элементами фокус начинается скакать по случайным textbox'ам. Вопрос следующий можно ли корректно использовать фокусировку по элементам и если да то как это сделать? Использую Avalonia 11.0.2 c Reactive, и паттерн MVVM.
Models:
public class Elements : ReactiveObject
{
    private int _id;
    private string _text;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _id, value);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _text, value);
    }
}

ViewModels:
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddNewRow { get; }

    private ObservableCollection<Elements> _elementsList;
    public ObservableCollection<Elements> ElementsList
    {
        get => _elementsList;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _elementsList, value);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ElementsList = new ObservableCollection<Elements>
        {
            new Elements { Id = 1, Text = "First item" }
        };

        AddNewRow = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
           
                ElementsList.Add(new Elements
                {
                    Id = ElementsList.Count + 1,
                    Text = $"Item {ElementsList.Count + 1}"
                });
            
        });
    }
}

View:
<Grid RowDefinitions="40,*">
   <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="New row" Command="{Binding AddNewRow}" />
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsList}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Elements}">
               <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" Margin="5">
                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                  <TextBox Tag="First" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" KeyDown="Control_KeyDown"
Loaded="Control_OnLoaded" />
                  <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Focusable="False" />
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

CodeBehind (Логика фокуса):
private void Control_OnLoaded(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var tb = sender as TextBox;
       
   if (tb.Tag == "First")
   {
      tb.Focus();
   }
}


private void Control_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
   {
      var tb = sender as TextBox;
      if (IsLastTextBox(tb)) // если Enter нажат в последнем TextBox-е, то нужно создать новую строку
      {
         CreateNewRow(tb);
      }
      else // иначе фокус должен переключиться на уже существующий TextBox
      {
         SwitchFocusToNextRow(tb);
      }
    }
 }


private bool IsLastTextBox(TextBox? tb)
{
   var nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(tb, NavigationDirection.Next);
   if (IsOurTextbox(nextElement)) // если tb - последний созданный TextBox, то за ним будет следовать не "наш" элемент
   {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}

// "нашим" является TextBox, помеченный либо First, либо Second
private bool IsOurTextbox(IInputElement? element)
{
  if (element is TextBox nextTb)
  {
     if (nextTb.Tag?.ToString() == "First")
     {
        return true;
     }
   }

   return false;
 }


 private void SwitchFocusToNextRow(TextBox? tb)
 {
    var nextElement = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(tb!, NavigationDirection.Next);
    nextElement?.Focus();
 }

 private void CreateNewRow(TextBox? tb)
 {
    if (DataContext is MainWindowViewModel dc)
    {
       dc.AddNewRow.Execute(Unit.Default).Subscribe();
            
    }
 }

Я поменял ItemsСontrol на ListBox так как узнал что сам контейнер имеет виртуализацию. Все здорово, теперь я могу хоть миллион текстбоксов сюда поместить и зависаний не будет никаких. Но сейчас возникла проблема следующая: все поведение фокуса пропало, кроме события загрузки, сейчас фокус идет на TextBox который подгружается благодаря виртуализации). А переключение фокуса между текстбоксами не работает и я считаю что это от того что я смотрю наличие текстбоксов внутри конкретного ListBox.Item и там он как-бы один и текстбокс соответственно создается новый (по моему условию). Так что сейчас беда с фокусом, еще буду думать что можно сделать.
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBox Tag="First" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" KeyDown="Control_KeyDown"/>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Focusable="False" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Также стилизовал так чтобы не было видно выбираемых элементов
<Style Selector="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ThemeForegroundBrush}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="ListBoxItem:selected">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ThemeForegroundBrush}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="ListBoxItem:pointerover">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>

Ну и вот видео соответственно как должно выглядеть (имею ввиду фокус): https://disk.yandex.ru/i/3ukrU_29pdnfng
И вот как сейчас: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/zCKgFCj3NUgjiA

Так WPF или Avalonia? И я бы использовал DataGrid для такой задачи вместо выдумывания велосипеда. Перед переключением фокуса на элемент, сделайте ему ScrollIntoView(). Ну или ListBox/ListView.

@aepot, делал с ListBox. Проблема остается

ScrollIntoView на целевом элементе пробовали? Ещё попробуйте перед втыканием фокуса из обработчика событий или команды, асинхронно подождать await Task.Delay(1), чтобы контрол успел обработать изменения в данных до игр с фокусом

К сожалению ничего не помогло. Я в avalonia работаю (вроде когда писал вопрос, указал), тут есть аналог ScrollIntoView, как я понял его надо на сам текстбокс в обработчике событий закинуть, но это не помогло. Сейчас сделал через ScrollViewer.Offset, вроде что то начало получатся, но все равно криво очень. Он будто элементы путает при фокусе, там по порядку идет по началу, но потом резко вверх окна фокус прыгает и потом уже какаято околесица) Сюда можно видео как-то приложить?

Может сама виртуализация как-то криво сделана у меня?

Приложите ссылками всё что хотите в сам вопрос. Ну и обновите его заодно, покажите, что именно пробовали.

Хорошо, позже предоставлю. Сейчас я понял одно, что следует использовать ListBox и не писать в нем VirtualizingStackPanel тк этот контейнер уже виртуализирован. Пока пробую упорядочить фокус, тк он вообще перестал работать
